# Undefined reference while creating object

Tags: c++

i am not able to create object of LO class. the code is below.

```
Tem.h
   #ifndef TEM_H_
   #define TEM_H_

   #include <iostream>
   #include <exception>
   #include "UDPTest.h"

   template<class T>
   class Tem : public std::exception {
   public:
    T* UDPt;
    Tem( T& t) throw();
    virtual ~Tem() throw();
   };

   template<class T>
   class LO :public Tem<T> {
    char* mez;
   public:
    LO() throw() ;
    char* what() const throw();
    virtual ~LO() throw();
   };

   template<class T>
   class AT :public Tem<T>{
    char* mez;
    public:
    AT() throw();
    char* what() const throw();
    virtual ~AT() throw();
    };
    #endif /* TEM_H_ */



Tem.cpp



#include "Tem.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template<class T>
Tem<T>::Tem(T& t) throw() : exception(){
UDPt = t;
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
template<class T>
Tem<T>::~Tem() throw() {
// TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

template<class T>
LO<T>::LO()  throw() {
cout<<"LO constructor"<<endl;
}
template<class T>
LO<T>::~LO() throw(){
}
template<class T>
char* LO<T>::what() const throw(){
return "Lockout validation failed.";
 }

template<class T>
AT<T>::AT() throw(){
cout<<"AT validation failed."<<endl;
}
template<class T>
char* AT<T>::what() const throw(){
return "Active Task validation failed.";
}
template<class T>
AT<T>::~AT() throw(){
}





UDPTest.h


#ifndef UDPTEST_H_
#define UDPTEST_H_

class UDPTest {
public:
int udp;
int tcp;
UDPTest();
virtual ~UDPTest();

};

#endif /* UDPTEST_H_ */




templatetest.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "Tem.h"
#include "UDPTest.h"
//#include <exception>
using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
try{
    throw LO<int>();
    //LO<int> loo;
}catch(exception& e){
    cout<<"got";
}
return 0;
}
```

in the main function i am creating LO class object and throwing, LO class is inheriting Tem class which is template, inside Tem class i have a pointer of UDPTest class.

As i know, i am doing mistake somewhere but i am not able to know. please help me

Thanks

Comment: there is undefined reference error, where i am throwing object. i don't know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using class templates in C++ you have to explicitly define the members of those classes with the declaration, in the header file, otherwise you won't be able to compile it.

(see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file))